# Silverlight Client logging

Tags: silverlight, logging, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to get some more Information about my Clients Silverlightactivity.
The System:
- Windows 7
- Internet Explorer 9
- Silverlight 5.1.30214.0

My goal is to log Information like Silverlight-Application access, Errors, etc.
If possible I would also like to get the "console" output, which is only visible in IE if the developer tools are activated.

Is there a way to do some automated logging regarding Silverlight?

Thank You!

Comment: Of course - error logging is a pretty well defined topic in all languages. You could write to DB, custom log file, windows logs. What have you tried, apart from the console which is of course pointless.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that more clear. I need to log/identify some issues. But I am not developing the Application(s).